# how to create a cartodb layer via post request

Tags: javascript, carto, google-maps-api

I have a select query (really long) based on which I want to create a layer on google maps. I tried the same query in cartodbo map editor(online) it worked fine. But when I wrote a code to access the same data via javascript its failing with the error

```
http://myusername.cartodb.com/api/v1/map?stat_tag=API&lzma=3YCAiIBsXICAgICA…c3R1fHUC1tGnX6s9z1OH8TOP0X8G%2FnjsaKGG3A%3D%3D&callback=_cdbc_2758786579_1
```

here is my code

```
var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 8,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(38.328732,-85.764771),
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
          };
          map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'),  mapOptions);

            cartodb.createLayer(map, {
              user_name: 'myusername',
              type: 'cartodb',
              sublayers: [{
                sql: "SELECT * FROM cartodb1 where zcta5ce10 in (" + zipList + ")",
                cartocss: '#cartodb1 {polygon-fill: #FF6600;polygon-opacity: 0.7;line-color: #FFF;line-width: 0.5;line-opacity: 1;}'}]
            })
            .addTo(map) // add the layer to our map which already contains 1 sublayer
            .done(function(layer) {
                console.log('Fine');
            })
            .error(function(e) {
                console.log(e);
            });

      }
```

where zip list is quite huge so I posted it separately here http://textuploader.com/ase80

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok found the solution! Was using older version of cartodb. As per @cge comments in [Dynamic rendering on a layer with a long SQL query](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/133699/dynamic-rendering-on-a-layer-with-a-long-sql-query)

Comment: tag your question as answered, please